# Show that finite additive set function is a measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Currently stuck on the following problem. Any help/suggestions are welcomed.

$\textbf{Problem.}$ Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{C})$ be a measurable space and let $\mu : \mathfrak{C} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a finitely additive function that satisfies all conditions of a measure except the $\sigma$-additivity. Show that if for each decreasing sequence of sets $A_{k} \in \mathfrak{C}$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\cap A_{k} = \emptyset$ we have $\lim_{k \to\infty} A_{k} = 0$, then $\mu$ is a measure.

$\textbf{Attempt at a solution.}$ Since the family of subsets $\{ A_{k} \}^{\infty}_{k = 1}$ is pairwise disjoint we also have that $\{ A_{k} \}^{n}_{k = 1}$ is pairwise disjoint. We then apply finite additivity such that

$$\Sigma^{\infty}_{k=1} \mu(A_{k}) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \Sigma^{n}_{k = 1} \mu(A_{k}) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(\cup^{n}_{k=1} A_{k}).$$

If we can show $ \lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(\cup^{n}_{k=1} A_{k}) = \mu(\cup^{\infty}_{k=1} A_{k})$, then we are done.

I also know that if $A_{1} \subseteq A_{2} \subseteq \ldots$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty} A_{k} = \cup^{\infty}_{k = 1} A_{k}$; if $A_{1} \supseteq A_{2} \supseteq \ldots$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty} A_{k} = \cap^{\infty}_{k = 1} A_{k}$. And that for convergence of sets, the limes inferior and limes superior are equal, i.e. we have $\cap^{\infty}_{k=1} A_{k} = \lim_{k\to\infty} A_{k} = 0 = \mu(\emptyset) = \mu(\cap^{\infty}_{k = 1} A_{k})$.

Comment: I guess when you write $\lim_k A_k =0$ what you really mean is $\lim_k \mu(A_k)=0$, right?

Comment: The problem statement from the homework assignment states $\lim A_{k} = 0$. Could be an error though since the lim sup and lim inf are sets and it does not make sense to say $lim A_{k} = 0$, does it?

Comment: Exactly. Also, if the assumption was not as I think it should be (that is $\lim_k \mu(A_k)=0$), then the assumptions don't say anything useful about $\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(A_k)$ be disjoint with union $A$ and consider $B_k=A \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} A_i$. Verify that $(B_k)$ is a decreasing sequence of sets with empty intersection. So $\mu (B_k) \to 0$ which implies $\mu(A)-\mu (\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} A_i) \to 0$. This gives $\mu(A)-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \mu (A_i) \to 0$.

Comment: $B_{1} = A_{2} \cup A_{3} \cup A_{4} \cup A_{5} \cup \ldots$, $B_{2} = A_{3} \cup A_{4} \cup A_{5} \cup \ldots$, $B_{3} = A_{4} \cup A_{5} \cup \ldots$, $\ldots$. Hence, $B_{1} \supset B_{2} \ldots $ and $\cap B_{k} = \emptyset$. How do I show that $\mu(B_{k}) \to 0$? By showing limes inferior = limes superior = 0?

Comment: @simpl0s It is **given** that $\mu(B_k) \to 0$ whenever $B_k$ is decreasing and the intersection is empty.  There is nothing to prove here.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Can't find this fact in my notes/literature.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right)$$ if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_{k+n}\right) = 0.$$ Therefore, to use the assumption, show that $$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_{k+n}$$ is a decreasing sequence of sets in $\mathfrak{C}$ such that $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_{k+n} = 0$$